# Word-of-mouth or word of mouth

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm confused about the "word-of-mouth" usage. I have encountered two variants: with a dash (word-of-mouth) and without it (word of mouth). Which is correct, or what is the difference in usage?

For example, "We can call social media a digital word of mouth of our company."

Comment: You don't really call something "**a** word of mouth" - word of mouth is just *how* something is transmitted.

Comment: What @stangdon said. Your example should say *We can call social media **the** digital **voice** of our company.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual convention is to optionally hyphenate a phrase if (a) it used as a compound adjective and (b) it is placed **before** the noun which it modifies, thus *the word-of-mouth distribution of the news meant that everyone knew before lunch time.*

Otherwise, no hyphens: *the news was passed by word of mouth.*

[Hyphen rules (Grammarbook.com)](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp)